# Convert time zones with Google?

Tags: google-search, time-zone

Can I convert time zone calculations (18:30 CEST to GMT+1 for example) with Google?

Comment: No, Google can't do that (yet). It has been suggested, though: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web+Search/thread?tid=585d9bcb419a2c9a&hl=en

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with WolframAlpha.

[18:30 CEST to GMT+1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18:30+CEST+to+GMT%2B1)

Comment: Beat me to it - they have an API as well : http://www.wolframalpha.com/developers.html

Comment: I used to use Google for small stuff but when I discovered WolframAlpha I was *deeply* impressed. At first because its ability to integrate/derive math functions. O:)

Answer (score 4):

[EveryTimeZone](http://everytimezone.com/) is a nice webapp that gives you a really quick simple view of the time (you can drag the 'current time' around) in various common time zones

Comment: This is a great little app that is perfect for figuring out what time it will be halfway across the world when you are trying to set up a time for a call with offshore teammates!

Answer (score 4):

Google currently does not do time conversions but you can always ask Google the current time at a location. Just search for "time in `<city>`" (e.g. time in london).

That is the way I use to quickly get the time in a different location. Of course you still have to calculate the difference yourself.

EDIT:
I just found out that this trick only works if the "interface language" for Google is set to English.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be working now (in 2018):

- https://www.google.de/search?q=8pm+est+to+pst
- https://www.google.de/search?q=18%3A30+CEST+to+GMT%2B1

Answer (score 2):

[Permatime](http://permatime.com/) is a nice little site that sets up a URL for your event time and displays it in  the viewers local time.

e.g. [The 2010 World Cup Final](http://permatime.com/Africa/Johannesburg/2010-07-11/20:30) in Johannesburg, South Africa.

Comment: I have not used permatime before, but it looks like an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found these:

http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc.tzc

http://www.onlineconversion.com/timezone.php

Google supplies a [reference page](http://www.google.com/Top/Reference/Time/Current_Time/) but doesn't seem to offer the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

I really like timeanddate.com's [interface](http://timeanddate.com/time/map/) and the Time Zone Converter near the bottom works well.